# Click event para matriz de botones

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy creando una matriz de botones mediante este codigo.

```
        private void Prueba_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = Negocios_Categorias_Menu.NroCategorias();
        DataTable ListaCat;
        ListaCat = Negocios_Categorias_Menu.Mostrar();
        int vertical1 = num / 3;
        int vertical2 = num % 3;
        if (vertical2!=0)
        {
            vertical1 = vertical1 + 1;
        }
        Button[,] boton = new Button[15, 3];
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertical1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (z < num)
                {
                    boton[i, j] = new Button();
                    boton[i, j].Width = 100;
                    boton[i, j].Height = 100;
                    boton[i, j].Text = ListaCat.Rows[z]["Categoria_Menu"].ToString(); ;
                    boton[i, j].Top = i * 100;
                    boton[i, j].Left = j * 100;
                    groupBox1.Controls.Add(boton[i,j]);
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Mi problema es al momento de crear el evento para un click en los botones, he probado varias soluciones propuestas en estos foros pero no he conseguido que funcione.

Comment: Sería bueno mostrar lo que no te ha funcionado, y el resultado de lo que no te ha funcionado (¿algún error? ¿cual?) y también explicar bien lo que necesitas que hagan los click de los botones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargalo manualmente al cargar los botones de la siguiente manera...

```
    ...
    Button[,] boton = new Button[15, 3];
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertical1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (z < num)
            {
                boton[i, j] = new Button();
                boton[i, j].Width = 100;
                boton[i, j].Height = 100;
                boton[i, j].Text = ListaCat.Rows[z]["Categoria_Menu"].ToString(); ;
                boton[i, j].Top = i * 100;
                boton[i, j].Left = j * 100;
                boton[i, j].Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
                groupBox1.Controls.Add(boton[i,j]);
                z++;
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Enseguida creas el metodo que hace el evento....

```
     void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          // Cuando se le da click al boton,
          // solo le cambiaremos el texto y lo ponemos enabled.

          Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
          clickedButton.Text = "Botón Click";
          clickedButton.Enabled = false;
     }
```

Pruebalo es que no se como funcione en arreglo, lo he probado solo para un boton...