# ¿Cómo crear botones con código en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy creando un sistema para un restaurante en **c#** y hay una sección que se llama buscar platillos pero quiero que en lugar de aparecer solo los nombres en un *DatagridView* me aparezcan en un *tablero* con *botones* para *manipularlo* mas fácil en una *pantalla táctil*. De esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que cada vez que inserte un platillo me genere un botón y poder desplazarme con las flechas como se ve en la imagen.
Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44032/click-event-para-matriz-de-botones/44037#44037 posiblemente eso es lo que necesitas

Comment: Hola.. en el link que ves arriba hay una solucion a un problema similar al tuyo. Es muy probable que tu pregunta termine cerrada por duplicada, pero si lo que ves alli te sirve, bienvenido!. Si no es asi, por favor explica las diferencias con ese caso, y agrega toda la informacion posible que la diferencie..

Comment: Yo en lugar de un DataGridView usaría un FlowPanelLayout, checa este video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxfYFAw0JDs

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, solo la matriz de botones al igual que el FlowPanel. Gracias a todos por responder