# Creación de botones dinámicos c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Alguien tiene conocimiento de cómo puedo crear más de un botón dinámico al tiempo en c#, el código que tengo permite crear un botón al tiempo el cual trae la información de un botón que esta localizado en otro formulario.

Muchas gracias.

```
//Abrimos el form2
            Form2 menu_fallas1 = new Form2();
            menu_fallas1.ShowDialog();

            //sumar en el array cada vez que se crea
            arrayBoton = new Button[contadorBotones + 1];

            //recuperar los datos
            string textBoton = Form2.textoboton;
            Image imagen = Form2.imagen;
            int alto = Form2.alto;
            int ancho = Form2.ancho;
         
            //crear boton
            Button nuevoboton = new Button();

            //asignar texto - propiedades
            nuevoboton.Text = textBoton;
            nuevoboton.Image = imagen;
            nuevoboton.Height = alto;
            nuevoboton.Width = ancho;
    
            //crear contador de botones
            int numbotones = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;

            //agregar al panel.
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(nuevoboton);

            //crear evento click
            nuevoboton.Click += new EventHandler(nuevoboton_Click);

            //guardar text del boton en el array
            arrayBoton[numbotones] = nuevoboton;

            //incrementar contador en 1  
            contadorBotones++;
}
```

Comment: Podrias anexar tu codigo por favor, y que tipo de proyecto es? web, windows form, wpf?

Comment: Es un proyecto windows form
            Button nuevoboton2 = new Button();

            nuevoboton2.Text = textBoton;
            nuevoboton2.Image = imagen;
            nuevoboton2.Height = alto;
            nuevoboton2.Width = ancho;
Estas variables las tomo del form2

Comment: Añade el código a la pregunta por favor

Comment: Sin duda alguien tendrá conocimiento de cómo puedes crear más de un botón dinámico.

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44037/182188) encontrarás una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: La duda es con tu codigo en particular? porque ese codigo ya genera un boton, pero al volver a ejecutarse lo pierde...

Comment: La duda con mi código es, como lo puedo modificar para que cree varios botones al tiempo?, En este momento si le doy clic al boton1 y luego al botón de home en el home me va a crear un botón dinámico en el home dentro de un flowLayoutPanel, lo que necesito es si le doy clic al boton1 y al boton2 me lo cree de la misma forma que lo esta haciendo, Muchas gracias.

Comment: me guie de este video para hacer la creación de los botones, con la diferencia que la información no la trae de un textbox si no del mismo botón https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XAXAxwnD4Qs

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo

```
Button[,] boton = new Button[10, 10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            boton[i, j] = new Button();
            boton[i, j].Width = 40;
            boton[i, j].Height = 20;
            boton[i, j].Text = String.Format("{0},{1}", i, j);
            boton[i, j].Top = i * 20;
            boton[i, j].Left = j * 40;
            this.Controls.Add(boton[i, j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trata de explicar que se hacia mal y que has hecho tu para arreglarlo, en vez de poner el codigo y ya. De esta forma entendera cualquier cosa del codigo.